# Missing jetty-servlet 12.0.0 dependency

Tags: java, jetty

I cannot find the `jetty-servlet` artifact for the recently released Jetty 12.0.0

- https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/releases/tag/jetty-12.0.0

A search for it shows that it is not present on Maven Central, where can I find it?  Does it still exist?

Comment: *Any ideas if and when these dependencies will be available in Maven Central in future?* I would ask that question the maintainers of jetty. They should be able to answer this

Comment: Ok, I found that, starting from 12.x, jetty dependencies will be released under different names (see https://eclipse.dev/jetty/documentation/jetty-12/programming-guide/index.html > "Migrating from Jetty 11.0.x to Jetty 12.0.x"). Example for EE10 (corresponding to Servlet 6.0, see to https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/): https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty.ee10/jetty-ee10-servlet.

Comment: The artifacts are there now, under different coordinates due to the introduction of the Environment concept in Jetty 12 (see answer below about why, and how to find the right coordinates)

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt: Thank you for the clarification. One more question - can you possibly estimate if and when jersey-container-jetty-servlet will support jetty 12? As far as I see the current release 3.1.3 of that library just supports jetty 11

Comment: Have to ask the Jersey folks that.

Comment: See https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/issues/5401

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The artifacts that are EE specific are now isolated in their own EE specific layer.

The design of Jetty 12 is that it is a Core, with no EE specifics (no Servlet, nothing) and then a bunch of Environments that provide the EE specific details.

With this new design...

- The long history (since 1995) of versioning in Jetty is more consistent with normal versioning expectations.

  - since 1995, Jetty versioning was `<servlet_support>.<major>.<minor>`
  - starting with Jetty 12 it is now `<major>.<minor>.<patch>`
- There will be fewer (if any) major version updates in Jetty.
- A new Jakarta EE or Jakarta Servlet version will just cause a new Environment to pop up.
- It is possible to run multiple Environments at the same time now.
- Continued support for legacy `javax.servlet` webapps.

Eg:

| Environment | Jakarta EE | Servlet | Namespace |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `ee8` | Jakarta EE 8 | Jakarta Servlet 4 | `javax.servlet.*` |
| `ee9` | Jakarta EE 9 | Jakarta Servlet 5 | `jakarta.servlet.*` |
| `ee10` | Jakarta EE 10 | Jakarta Servlet 6 | `jakarta.servlet.*` |

See the documentation about migrating from Jetty 11 to Jetty 12, and specifically the table of the maven coordination changes.

https://eclipse.dev/jetty/documentation/jetty-12/programming-guide/index.html#pg-migration-11-to-12