# org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler is missing

Tags: java, jetty

I`m using oracle openJDK 20 with maven.

```xml
<properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>20</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>20</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
            <version>12.0.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.18</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

And i cant use `org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler`, becouse this class exetends `org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler`, but it is missing

I tried to search this problem and found nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not mix versions of Jetty.

All of your Jetty artifacts should be on the same version of Jetty.

Also, you should read the documentation on Jetty 12 (pay attention to "environments")

- [Jetty 12 Documentation Hub](https://eclipse.dev/jetty/documentation/jetty-12/)
- [Jetty 11 to Jetty 12 Migration Guide](https://eclipse.dev/jetty/documentation/jetty-12/programming-guide/index.html#pg-migration-11-to-12)
- [Maven Coordinates have Changed](https://webtide.com/new-jetty-12-maven-coordinates/)
- [Missing jetty-servlet 12.0.0 dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77007560/missing-jetty-servlet-12-0-0-dependency/77010707#77010707)

The artifact `jetty-servlet` does not exist in Jetty 12, as Jetty 12 is based on environments (with support for multiple environments at the same time in different webapps).

You have to decide which environment you want to use and then use the appropriate maven coordinates.

Example: you seem to want to use Servlet 6.0, that would belong to the environment labeled `ee10`, so use those artifacts.