# Jetty Servlet dependency issue while upgrading from Springboot 3.1.6 to 3.2.x

Tags: spring, spring-boot, servlets, jetty, pom.xml

Seeing this error when attempting to upgrade to Springboot 3.2.x from 3.1.6, need help in resolving it:

```
ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlets:jar is missing.
```

And the line in question:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty-servlets</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Tried adding valid versions or the `jakarta-servlet.version` property as referenced [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide)

Comment: Well there is no version as the error states, and it probably was removed from dependency management from Spring Boot hence you need to supply a version yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The `jetty-servlets` artifact from Jetty 5 thru Jetty 11 provides supplemental Servlets (like QOSFilter, and DOSFilter).  Note: Jetty 12 has many of those filters deprecated and replaced with non-servlet options.

Back in those releases of Jetty, the servlet API was intertwined with the server itself.

But in Jetty 12, the servlet API is no longer present in the core jetty server.

Any prior artifact that required Servlet, have been relegated to Environments in Jetty 12.

See prior answer:

- [Missing jetty-servlet 12.0.0 dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77007560/missing-jetty-servlet-12-0-0-dependency/77010707#77010707)

And other links

- [Jetty 11 to Jetty 12 migration guide](https://eclipse.dev/jetty/documentation/jetty-12/programming-guide/index.html#pg-migration-11-to-12)
- [New Jetty 12 Maven Coordinates](https://webtide.com/new-jetty-12-maven-coordinates/)