# Porting AbstractHandler implementation from Jetty 11 to Jetty 12

Tags: java, jetty, jetty-12

I have a class that extends `AbstractHandler` and overrides the `handle` method like this:

```
@Override
public void handle(String target, Request baseRequest, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws IOException {

    // implementation details
```

}

However, I see that `AbstractHandler` is deprecated in Jetty 12 and the method signature for `handle` has changed:

```
@Override
public boolean handle(Request request, Response response, Callback callback) throws Exception {
    
}
```

**My questions are:**

- How can I access the `baseRequest` and `request` objects that I rely on in my Jetty 11 implementation?
- What is the proper way to port my `AbstractHandler` subclass to work in Jetty 12?

Here is a summary of what my handler is doing:

- Checks `HttpServletRequest` headers
- Sets `HttpServletResponse` headers based on `Request` headers

Any help or examples of properly migrating an `AbstractHandler` implementation from Jetty 11 to Jetty 12 would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you appear to want is either `Handler.Abstract` or `Handler.Wrapper`.

There is documentation on both at

- https://eclipse.dev/jetty/documentation/jetty-12/programming-guide/index.html

And there are examples in the jetty-examples project at

- https://github.com/jetty/jetty-examples

Such as [`FormEndpoints`](https://github.com/jetty/jetty-examples/blob/12.0.x/embedded/form-post/src/main/java/examples/FormEndpoints.java) (along with others in the `/embedded/` tree)

In short, you have an immutable `Request` and a mutable `Response`.

The [`Request`](https://eclipse.dev/jetty/javadoc/jetty-12/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Request.html) is a special purpose [`Content.Source`](https://eclipse.dev/jetty/javadoc/jetty-12/org/eclipse/jetty/io/Content.Source.html) for HTTP which handles the read/demand behaviors of the incoming request (be sure to check out the static methods on both of these types, as there are many handy convenience methods for common tasks)

The [`Response`](https://eclipse.dev/jetty/javadoc/jetty-12/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Response.html) is a special purpose [`Content.Sink`](https://eclipse.dev/jetty/javadoc/jetty-12/org/eclipse/jetty/io/Content.Sink.html) for HTTP which handles the write behaviors of the outgoing request (also look at the static methods on these two types as well).

The [`boolean Handler.handle(Request, Response, Callback)`](https://eclipse.dev/jetty/javadoc/jetty-12/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Request.Handler.html#handle(org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request,org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response,org.eclipse.jetty.util.Callback)) method has the following contract.

- Returning `true` means that this Handler is going to handle the request.  This means no further `Handler` implementations will be called by the Server dispatch.  (this was the equivalent of `baseRequest.setHandled(true)` in Jetty 11 and older)
- The `Callback` **MUST** eventually be completed by calling `success()` or `failure()` on it. (many of the methods can take the Callback and do the success/failure for you, eg: `Response.write`, `Content.Sink.write`, etc)
- Returning `true` does not complete/finish the request/response, only the callback completes the request/response.

If you want to mutate the request (to change something about it) for a different handler, then you must use a `Handler.Wrapper` and wrap the incoming request in a `Request.Wrapper` that modifies things to suite your needs and then call the nested handler.

Tip: if you can avoid using the Stream APIs from Content.Sink and Content.Source you'll have far better performance (and less resource use) in your webapp.  But we know that sometimes that is not possible, so don't hesitate to use them.

Comment: Thanks Joakim, I understand `Request` object remains the same in signature if I use just have to use different methods like `request.getHeaders().get()` but how can I access `HttpServletRequest` object or `HttpServletResponse` object?

Our previous implementation used get headers from `HttpServletRequest` object  and modify `HttpServletResponse` object. I apologies if this question very trivial.

Comment: Jetty core has no servlet layer anymore.  The servlet layer only exists in the various environments now.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77007560/missing-jetty-servlet-12-0-0-dependency/77010707#77010707

Comment: If you want to use servlet techniques, then use the environment specific `ServletContextHandler` and use `addServlet()` against it.  See https://github.com/jetty/jetty-examples/tree/12.0.x/embedded/ee10-form-post